# Is render method obliged in React always?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I learn by doing React and I was thinking that `render` method in React is obliged, but I saw following component:

```
export const GoogleButton = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    height: 55,
    width: 255,
    margin: theme.spacing(5, 0, 2),
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    justifyContent: 'start',
    background: theme.palette.background.default,
  },
  startIcon: {
    marginRight: 20,
    paddingRight: 3,
    borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.text.primary}`,
    background: 'none',
  },
}))(Button);

type AllProps = OwnProps & StateProps & DispatchProps;

export const GoogleLoginButtonPure = ({ isInProgress, login }: AllProps) => {
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => login(), [login]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <GoogleButton
      disabled={isInProgress}
      onClick={handleClick}
      fullWidth
      variant="contained"
      startIcon={GOOGLE_ICON}
    >
      {t('login.button')}
    </GoogleButton>
  );
};
```

The code works smoothly but anyone can explain me why that component does not have `render` method?

Comment: That's a function component which has a `return` statement. Read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render method is only used in class components. Your component is a functional so cannot use render method.